# Copy parquet table between CDH clusters

Tags: cloudera, impala

I need to copy parquet table from CDH4.5 to CDH4.3 cluster, to do so:

- used distcp to copy directory with data (/user/hive/warehouse/mytable)
- compared directory sizes
- fixed permissions and ownership to look the same on both clusters (777 and impala:hive)
- opened impala-shell and created the table
- invalidated metadata `invalidate metadata`
- refreshed table `refresh mytable`

All good but impala doesn't see data. Impala restart doesn't help either. Is it possible to make it see copied data?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, the problem is that the table is partitioned and you need to re-create partitions manually in this case:

```
alter table mytable add partition(time=12341313131)
```